# Defining the status of a LLC

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, state-income-tax

This takes place in the USA.
I sent the documents that are required to close my LLC but never got confirmation that it was dissolved.

Throughout the whole time I ran it, I was never able to log into the FTB's website using the EIN number I got when opening it. Not being able to go on the FTB website was actually one of the most frustrating things about the LLC.

**Now I would like to be sure it was dissolved. Is there a way to know for sure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EIN should have been registered via the IRS, not the FTB (which I assume is the California Franchise Tax Board). If you registered your LLC in CA, you should contact (by phone) the California Secretary of State (https://www.sos.ca.gov/business-programs/business-entities/contact).

Comment: You can also search for your LLC on the Calif. website: https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/   The meaning of the 'Status' field is here: https://www.sos.ca.gov/business-programs/business-entities/cbs-field-status-definitions

Comment: Thank you Orange Coast. Your comment actually solved the problem!!